# Macho runpath is being modified when deployed on a different machine

Tags: macos, linker, dylib, runpath

I've set the search path of libcrpyto inside my dylib file to lookup for libcrypto.1.1.dylib in the following path :

```
otool -L mylib.dylib
-->
...
@rpath/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
...
```

However, when I deploy the target into a certain machine in which I've once have built libcrypto, than the search path is being automatically replaced from rpath to the location of my previous build target.

```
otool -L mylib.dylib
-->
...
/Users/me/Developer/staging/fakeroot/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
...
```

The file remains unchanged of course (check it by matching md5 on file content)

I've looked if there's any environment variable that might replace @rpath to `/Users/me/Developer/staging/fakeroot/lib/` but haven't found any variable that include the once used path.

Perhaps it's something that defined inside the file ? but what is the reason I get this path only in this specific machine ?

Comment: How exactly does your deployment process look like?

Comment: @Siguza, My deployment uses pkg format to copy the contents into their correct location on disk. I can say that when I opened the pkg file on another machine, it worked. so I'm suspecting that it happens on this particular setup is because I once built libssl and pointed the output to this fakeroot location. I just don't sure where is the environment variable that convert my @rpath to `/Users/me/Developer/staging/fakeroot`